# Como obtener un mensaje en el formulario a través de ajax?

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, json, spring

Tengo el siguiente método en mi controller,

```html
@RequestMapping(value="view/obtieneInfo")
@ResponseBody
public  JsonResponse obtieneInfor(@ModelAttribute("consultaForm") Factura fact, Model model, HttpServletRequest request) throws ControlException{

JsonResponse response = new JsonResponse();
response.setExito(0);
response.setDatos(null);
try{
List<Factura> factList = obtieneInfoService.consultaDatos(id, cvePag, fecha);
if(factList !=null && !factList.isEmpty){
 response.setExito(1);
 response.setDatos(factList);

}else{
  log.info("Esta vacio");
}
}catch(ControlException e){
   throw new ControlException("Error", e);
}
return response;
}
```

Lo que quiero hacer es que cuando en mi formulario se ingresen los datos , se pasen como parametro al metodo del servicio, ya lo hace, y si no encuentra datos, que mande un mensaje a la vista, en un modal, que diga, no se encontraron datos, sin recargar la pagina

Este es mi codigo de la vista

```html
function consultar(){
var valido = true;
var valId = document.getElementaryById('idPago').value;
var valClavePago = document.getElementaryById('clavePago').value;
var valFecha = document.getElementaryById('fechaPago').value;

if(valId.trim() =="" && valClavePago.trim() == "" && valFecha.trim() == ""){

  HelperDialogs.mostrar("Debes ingresar al menos un valor");
  valido = false;
}
  return valido;
}

function obtieneInf(){
var data = Helper.obtenerJsonForm(consulta);
$.ajax({
type:"POST",
contentType: "application/json",
url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/view/obtieneInf",
data: data,
success: function(data){
if(data.exito==1){
 HelperDialogo.mostrar("Si hay registros");
}else{
  HelperDialogo.mostrar("No se encontraron registros");
}

},
error: function(e){
console.log("Error", e);
HelperDialogo.mostrar(e);
}

}
});
}
<form:form id="consulta" modelAttribute="consultaForm">
  <tr>
    <td><label>ID/label></td>
    <td><form: input type="text"  id="idPago" path="id"/></td>
   </tr>
   
   <tr>
    <td><label>CLAVE PAGO</label></td>
    <td><form: input type="text" id="clavePago" path="clavePago"/></td>
   </tr>
   
   <tr>
   
   
   <tr>
    <td><label>FECHA PAGO</label></td>
    <td><form: input type="text" id="fechaPago" path="fechaPago"/></td>
    <input type="submit" onclick="consultar()"></input>
   </tr>
</form:form>
```

Esa función la mando a llamar en la readyfunction,
y lo que hace es que me manda a otra pagina, para ambos casos de que si hay y no hay datos, y los muestra como json, pero no me manda el dialogo que es lo que quiero que salga en la misma pagina,
como le puedo hacer?
que me hace falta?
Gracias

Comment: A ver si lo entiendo. El problema es que cuando envías el formulario te redirecciona a otra pagina y en vez de eso to quieres que se quede en la misma mostrando un dialogo?

Comment: Es correcto, me redirecciona  a otra pagina y muestra el json, y yo queiro que salga el modal en la misma página que diga hay o no hay datos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una causa es que el navegador envía el formulario de forma normal después de que se haya enviado a través de ajax.

Para prevenir al navegador enviar el formulario de forma normal, una opción es cambiar el tipo del botón que envía el formulario de `submit` a `button`, y el `onclick` para que llame a la función que envía la solicitud:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="consultar()"></input>
```

a

```
<input type="button" onclick="obtieneInf()"></input>
```

Y modificar javascript para leer correctamente la respuesta JSON que recibes del servidor:

```
function obtieneInf() {

  // Validar formulario
  if (!consultar()) {
    return false;
  }

  var data = Helper.obtenerJsonForm(consulta);
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/view/obtieneInf",
    data: data,
    success: function(data) {
      // Formatear respuesta como JSON
      let respuesta = JSON.parse(data);

      if (respuesta.exito == 1) {
        HelperDialogo.mostrar("Si hay registros");
      } else {
        HelperDialogo.mostrar("No se encontraron registros");
      }

    },
    error: function(e) {
      console.log("Error", e);
      HelperDialogo.mostrar(e);
    }

  });
}
```

Comment: Gracias, me ayudo